# Add item to existing legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am new to `ggplot2` and I am struggling since hours to add a second legend in my plot.

I am using two `data.frames` (`df_1` and `df_2`) and two `geom_point` calls for them. I managed to create a legend for `df_2` **but I was not able to add a second legend for `df_1`.**

Here a code example with also plot:

```
########## Create sample data
set.seed(69)
df_1 = data.frame(lat = rnorm(20), 
                  lon = rnorm(20), 
                  cor = c(rep('positive', 12), rep('negative', 8)), 
                  sign = 0)

df_2 = data.frame(lat = rnorm(20), 
                  lon = rnorm(20), 
                  cor = c(rep('positive', 7), rep('negative', 13)), 
                  sign = c(rep(99, 5), rep(95, 6), rep(90,9)))

#### Plot data
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot() +

    # geom_point for df_1
    geom_point(data=df_1, aes(x=lon, y=lat), 
               alpha=0.7, color = 'darkgrey', size = 3) +

    # geom_point for df_2
    geom_point(data=df_2, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=sign, colour = cor), alpha = 0.5) +

    scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"),
                       name='cor', 
                       labels = c('neg', 'pos'),
                       guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1, size = 3))) +

    scale_size(range = c(1,3), 
               breaks = c(90, 95, 99),
               labels = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.01),
               name = 'sign',
               guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = 'black', 
                                                        alpha = 1)))

print(p)
```

[image]

**How can I add a legend for the `geom_point` call of `df_1`?**

It would be enough to add a 3rd darkgrey point to cor (right legend) with label 'not sign'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the straightforward solution is too do what you ask *add 3rd darkgrey point to cor legend*. To do this you have to:

1. Change `cor` values in `df_1` to be all the same.
2. Specify color in `df_1` `aes`.
3. Add information for the third point in `scale_color_manual`.

Code:

```
# Change values so we would have single color for them
df_1$cor <- "foo" 

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(lon, lat, color = cor), df_1,
               alpha = 0.7, size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(lon, lat, size = sign, colour = cor), df_2,
               alpha = 0.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgrey", "red", "blue"),
                       labels = c("not sign", "neg", "pos"),
                       guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1, size = 3))) +
    scale_size(range = c(1, 3), 
               breaks = c(90, 95, 99),
               labels = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.01),
               guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "black", alpha = 1)))
```

Result:

[image]